# What is the best book on threat modeling that you've read?

Tags: threat-modeling

I have been involved with developing threat models for several software products and features, and I'd like to formalize this process a little bit and create some documentation for my company's devs. Can you guys recommend a good book that describes all the essential components of building a good threat model?

I've skimmed [Window Snyder's book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735619913), but didn't find it particularly engaging. I wouldn't expect this to be a 300 page topic, but maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The Art of Software Security Assessment gives a nod to UML class diagrams as a design generalization assessment approach.

For one of the most interesting techniques on this (that Cigital adopted for their "threat-modeling" approach) is from a book called "Applying UML and Patterns", where it covers Architectural Risk Analysis.

Rohit Sethi also started a project for OWASP called "Securing the Core JEE Patterns". It's only a short paper, but definitely the coolest thing I've ever seen in the threat-modeling world.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest reading about DREAD and STRIDE.  I also recommend Chapter 4 of Writing Secure Code.

However, don't get your hopes up too much.  Architectural risk analysis (what Microsoft calls "threat modeling") is inherently an ad-hoc art.  It requires deep domain knowledge about the system being modelled; and some knowledge of security concepts and experience with this sort of security analysis helps, too.